# Android app starts pulling old SharedPreferences when crossing a certain versionCode

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Noticed that my app started showing some old data from`SharedPreferences` after uninstall-install cycle.

After some digging, turned out that it started pulling `SharedPreferences` files from 21 build versions ago. Say I'm at buildVersion `500` now, the shared prefs I'm seeing are from `479`.

No matter which codebase I use, I went as far as a release from a year back, set versionCode to `500` - the issue presents itself.

No specific `BackupManager`s or any sorts of migration code for prefs.

Yes, `allowBackup` is set to `true`, and setting it to `false` fixes the issue, but I really want to get to the bottom of it. Nothing in the docs specifically mentions it.

What could be causing it?

Comment: Isn't this how it's supposed to work if `allowBackup` is set to `true`? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#allowBackup

Comment: `allowBackup` set to `true` means the app participates in Auto Backup which backs up SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup. It's unclear how the versionCode is relevant in this case - maybe different versions of the app targeted different api levels

Comment: @VCODE, that's what I thought, but why wasn't this happening before if it was set to `true` the entire time, as well as why isn't this happening when the versionCode is lower than a certain number?

Comment: @KenWolf, I agree, this doesn't make sense. Has nothing to do with the API levels, I tested on a number of release tags and it religiously pulls that particular copy of shared prefs with version code `479` as soon as I apply `versionCode="500"` to any of those, no matter what `versionName` is.

Comment: @SergP maybe the last backup for that user was taken around the time they were using versionCode `479` of the app? See the schedule and requirements here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#BackupSchedule

Comment: @KenWolf, makes sense, but doesn't explain why `479` backup is not applied to any other versionCodes between `480` and `499`. I'll try https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup .